# SQL AVG Function with with a time format

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

So I am using Google Big Query, and I want to find the average time for my entire column. The time is formatted as hh:mm:ss for the entire column, for example 00:19:00.

```
select 
 AVG(ride_length) AS average_duration
FROM `casestudy1-361603.project.DecData`
```

However there is an error saying, "No matching signature for aggregate function AVG for argument types: STRING".

[This is how the column looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0aKVA.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cast strings to [interval datatype](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#interval_type) and perform an average:

```
select avg(cast(t as interval)) as agg
from unnest(['10:20:30', '30:40:50']) as t
```

returns

| agg |
| --- |
| 0-0 0 20:30:40 |

**UPD**: If you want to extract specific parts of the result, you may use [`justify_interval`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/interval_functions#justify_interval) to normalize interval to standard day duration (24h) and use [`extract` function](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/interval_functions#extract) to extract portions.

```
with src as (
  select avg(cast(t as interval)) as agg
  from unnest(['70:20:30', '40:40:50']) as t
)
select
  src.agg,
  justify_interval(agg) as normalized_,
  extract(hour from justify_interval(agg)) as h
from src
```

| agg | normalized_ | h |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0-0 0 55:30:40 | 0-0 2 7:30:40 | 7 |

Comment: Is there anyway that I can extract the minutes and combine both the hour and minute together in a single cell, instead of having one column for hour and another column for minute?

Comment: As long as `cast` for interval doesn't support `format` option, you may build a `case` expression to fill proper parts in the output or use single regex to split ISO-formatted string into parts: `regexp_replace(cast(justify_interval(agg) as string), '(\\d+)-(\\d+) (\\d+) (\\d+):(\\d+):(\\d+)(.(\\d+))?', '\\1 years \\2 months \\3 days \\4 hours \\5 minutes \\6 seconds \\8 microseconds"")')`