# Calculate average time from column with data type "*TIME*"

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, average, aggregate-functions

Input data:

| start_datetime | end_datetime | time_difference |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-08-11 07:57:00 UTC | 2022-08-11 08:06:00 UTC | 00:09:49 |
| 2022-06-04 19:09:00 UTC | 2022-06-04 19:27:00 UTC | 00:17:57 |
| 2022-11-11 09:38:00 UTC | 2022-11-11 09:52:00 UTC | 00:13:49 |
| 2022-04-28 12:44:00 UTC | 2022-04-28 12:57:00 UTC | 00:13:27 |
| 2022-04-24 19:12:00 UTC | 2022-04-24 19:56:00 UTC | 00:44:31 |

I want to calculate average time of column with datatype TIME (saved in format HH:MM:SS). It is derived from 2 columns start_datetime and end_datetime.

I was able to calculate average using the following application of functions:

```
TIME(
    TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(
        CAST(AVG(DATETIME_DIFF(end_datetime,
                               start_datetime,
                               SECOND)) AS INT64)
    )
)
```

However, since it is using INT64, it is not accurate to the second and using FLOAT64 is not supported:

> No matching signature for function TIMESTAMP_SECONDS for argument types: FLOAT64. Supported signature: TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(INT64) at [1:49]*

This is the difference I can see with this query:

```
SELECT start_datetime, 
       end_datetime, 
       time_difference,
       TIME(
           TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(
               CAST(DATETIME_DIFF(end_datetime,
                                  start_datetime,
                                  SECOND) AS INT64)
           )
       ) AS time_difference_calculated 
FROM `cleaned_ok_new` 
LIMIT 5
```

**Output**:

| Row | start_datetime | end_datetime | time_difference | time_difference_calculated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-08-11 07:57:00 UTC | 2022-08-11 08:06:00 UTC | 00:09:49 | 00:09:00 |
| 2 | 2022-06-04 19:09:00 UTC | 2022-06-04 19:27:00 UTC | 00:17:57 | 00:18:00 |
| 3 | 2022-11-11 09:38:00 UTC | 2022-11-11 09:52:00 UTC | 00:13:49 | 00:14:00 |
| 4 | 2022-04-28 12:44:00 UTC | 2022-04-28 12:57:00 UTC | 00:13:27 | 00:13:00 |
| 5 | 2022-04-24 19:12:00 UTC | 2022-04-24 19:56:00 UTC | 00:44:31 | 00:44:00 |

Tried reference of [SQL AVG Function with with a time format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73607034/sql-avg-function-with-with-a-time-format)
but got following error:

> Invalid cast from TIME to INTERVAL at [1:50]

Comment: Can you update your post with sample input data?

Comment: hi @lemon , i have added input data in question. Let me know if you need it in any other format

Comment: Yes. These are the relevant columns.

Comment: Is the expected output already in your post? If it's not, can you add it?

Comment: how about `select avg(cast(LTRIM(DATEDIFF(second, 0, time_difference)) as int)) from cleaned_ok_new`

Comment: Hi, thanks. However, getting following error
Unrecognized name: second at [1:70]

Comment: Tried following <br>
'SELECT 
      end_datetime,
      start_datetime, 
      time_difference, 
      AVG(CAST(LTRIM(DATE_DIFF(end_datetime,start_datetime,SECOND)) AS INT64)) 
FROM cleaned_ok_new LIMIT 5 ' <br>
Error is - <br>
'No matching signature for function LTRIM for argument types: INT64. Supported signatures: LTRIM(STRING, [STRING]); LTRIM(BYTES, BYTES) at [5:16]'